# Disable Jenkins job for set amount of time

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that deploys an artifact to a server. I want to give the job runner the ability to disable the job for a set amount of time - could be one hour, could be one month. I also want them to have to enter a reason. The reason (along with various other info - build name, runner name etc.) then needs to be emailed to a distribution list.

Is there a way to disable a job for a set amount of time from within itself, on successful completion?

I'm guessing I need the parameterised build plugin, which I'm already successfully using for a couple of jobs.

EDIT:
I'm thinking I could do this by checking for a lock file in a pre-step, and writing a lock file either containing or named for the time at which the build becomes unlocked. I thought there might be a plugin or something I could use instead though.

Comment: Sorry if this is spammy, but the [CloudBees Skip Next Build](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/jenkins-enterprise/plugins/skip-next-build-plugin) plugin does this. Available with a subscription.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but considering I can do it in an ugly way for free, I'm not going to pay just for convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I went with my method in the end. Using a parameterised build (using the Parameterised Build Plugin), I ask the builder to enter the date they wish the job to be locked until. This is then written to a .lock file as a post-build step.

Subsequently, as a pre-build step, I look for a .lock file and read the contents. I then compare the date in the file to the current date, and either fail the build if the job is locked, or continue.

The code is below.

Pre-Step:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ''
EXIT_CODE=0
LOCK_FILE_NAME=$DEPLOYMENT_ENV'.lock'

#Check chosen branch isn't master
if [ $BRANCH_NAME = 'master' ]
then
        echo 'This job is for building feature branches. To build master, use the Deploy Master Artifact To Staging job.'
        EXIT_CODE=666;
else
#Check if lock file exists for selected environment
if [ -f $LOCK_FILE_NAME ] 
then
    echo 'Lock file found for' $DEPLOYMENT_ENV
    FILE_CONTENTS=`head -n 1 $LOCK_FILE_NAME`
    LOCK_DATE=`date -d $FILE_CONTENTS +'%Y%m%d'`
    NOW=`date +'%Y%m%d'`
    #Compare lock date to today. Has the lock expired?
    if [ $NOW -gt $LOCK_DATE ]
    then
        echo $DEPLOYMENT_ENV 'no longer locked. Proceeding with deployment...'
    else
        echo 'Job locked until:' `date -d $LOCK_DATE +'%d-%m-%Y'`
        echo 'Aborting job...'
        EXIT_CODE=666
    fi
else
    echo 'No lock file present for' $DEPLOYMENT_ENV
    echo 'Proceeding with deployment...'
fi
echo ''
exit $EXIT_CODE
```

Post-Step:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '**********' $WORKSPACE
#Copy artifact to web server
#Start web server
#Set lock
echo 'Now lock the environment until:' $LOCK_UNTIL;
echo $LOCK_UNTIL > $WORKSPACE'/'$DEPLOYMENT_ENV'.lock'
```

Scripting isn't really my forte, so if anyone has any better suggestions I'd be pleased to hear them :)